# Обновление базы данных без потери данных

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте, есть таблица, где 3 столбца: `id, name, favorite`.

Так вот, в `favorite` записывается 1 или 0, по умолчанию 0, он меняется если пользователь добавляет строку в Избранное.

Проблема в том, что если я обновляю базу данных (добавляю больше строк), все Избранные исчезают у пользователя.
Как перенести Избранные из старой базы данных в новую в методе `onUpgrade` ?

Код класса `DatabaseHelper`

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static String DB_NAME = "filessedetede.db";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 2;
    static final String MY_TABLE = "names";

    public static final String ID_COLUMN = "_id";
    public static final String NAME_COLUMN = "name";
    public static final String FAVORITE_COLUMN = "favorite";

    public SQLiteDatabase database;
    private Context mContext;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        mContext = context;
        initialize();
    }

    public void open() throws SQLException{
        //Open the database
        String myPath = mContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).toString();
        database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }

    /**
     * Initializes database. Creates database if doesn't exist.
     */
    public void initialize() {
        if (databaseExists()) {
            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
            int dbVersion = prefs.getInt("SP_KEY_DB_VER", 1);
            if (DB_VERSION != dbVersion) {
                try {
                    open();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                File dbFile = mContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME);
                if (!dbFile.delete()) {
                    Log.w("TAG", "Unable to update database");
                }
            }
        }
        if (!databaseExists()) {
            createDatabase();
        }
    }

    private boolean databaseExists() {
        File dbFile = mContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME);
        return dbFile.exists();
    }

    private void createDatabase() {
        String parentPath = mContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getParent();
        String path = mContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getPath();

        File file = new File(parentPath);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            if (!file.mkdir()) {
                Log.w("TAG", "Unable to create database directory");
                return;
            }
        }

        InputStream is = null;
        OutputStream os = null;
        try {
            is = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
            os = new FileOutputStream(path);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                os.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            os.flush();
            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putInt("SP_KEY_DB_VER", DB_VERSION);
            editor.commit();
            editor.apply();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (is != null) {
                try {
                    is.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (os != null) {
                try {
                    os.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if(oldVersion < newVersion){
           //Вот здесь как перекинуть Избранные из старой базы в новую
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, нарисуйте схему вашей базы, приведите код с маппингом и поясните, какие именно данные вы добавляете. Скорее всего, проблема в fetch, но нужно смотреть по базе.

Comment: @naiad09 Схему нарисовать сейчас не могу, но там и так простая база. Короче, есть готовая база данных, которую я ставлю в android приложение. 3 столбца: id,name,favorite. 
ListView заполняю значениями Name, favorite. Если favorite 0, то checkbox не отмечен, если 1 то отмечен, и естественно если пользователь отмечает checkbox сам, то меняю в базе значение favorite определенного id. Но, если я добавлю в базу еще значения (добавляю я не в самом приложении а отдельно через программу SqliteBrowser) то у меня такой код,что если новая версия базы данных, то старая база стирается и записывается новая

Comment: @naiad09 но мне нужно вытащить данные favorite из старой базы и пихнуть их в новую

Comment: Во-первых, то, что вы называете "базой данных", называется "таблица базы данных". Во-вторых, как говорил Линус, "болтовня ничего не стоит, покажите мне код".

Comment: @naiad09 добавил код, сейчас в этом коде такой процесс, если поменять версию базы, то старая база удаляется и записывается новая с файла.